# i have integrating Facebook how to get the user profile details in iOS 7

Tags: facebook, ios7

I have integrating Facebook in iOS 7, how to get getting user full profile and email & phone number from Facebook iOS 7.

```Objective-C
[[FBRequest requestForMe]
startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *FBFULLUSERDETAIL, NSError *error)
{
    if (error) {
        // Handle error
    }       
    else {
        // NSString *userName = [FBuser name];            
        // NSString *phonenumber =[FBuser id];            
        NSString *userImageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large", [FBFULLUSERDETAIL objectID]];                       
        NSLog(@"%@",FBFULLUSERDETAIL);
    }
}];
```

I need Facebook user email id and phone number and profile picture..
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should always try to solve your problem yourself. and if you have what have you tried?

Comment: there is no way to get the phone number - and for profile info and email, you need to authorize a user. this is where you need to go: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios